# No se asigna la variable SESSION que creo

Tags: php, session

Tengo un código, en donde un usuario puede actualizar su contraseña,
Al momento de actualizarla, se destruyen las sesiones y mando al usuario a loggearse de nuevo.
Justo luego de destruir las sesiones, creo una variable "nuevo" la cual da cuenta de la nueva contraseña.

```
session_destroy();              //destruyo las sessiones
$_SESSION['nuevo'] = "nuevo";   //asigno la nueva session
header("location: login.php");  //cambio a login
exit();
```

Pero por el lado del login, no logro recibir dicha variable recién creada.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();} //session_start
if (!isset($_SESSION['nuevo'])) {       //contengo el error
    $_SESSION['nuevo'] = "error";       //Asigno un valor en caso de error
}
echo var_dump($_SESSION["nuevo"]);      //imprimo la variable
```

Y el resultado que siempre obtengo en "error", como si nunca se asignara la variable creada.
La idea es asignar la variable antes de volver al login, para reconocerla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, era algo tan obvio, que no me lo creo jaja
luego de destruir las variables, hay que volver a iniciarlas.
Para ello hay que volver a añadir el `session_start()`

```
session_destroy();
session_start();
$_SESSION['nuevo'] = "nuevo";
header("location: login.php");
exit();
```